# Convert JSON to strongly typed objects

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting the following [json](/questions/tagged/json) as a response and I would like to convert it into an object.

```
WebSQLRows {
  "_array": Array [
    Object {
      "bmi": 24.7,
      "id": 1,
      "imperialgoalweight": 154.3,
      "imperialheight": 70.9,
      "imperialweight": 176.4,
      "metricgoalweight": 70,
      "metricheight": 180,
      "metricweight": 80,
      "standard": "Metric",
    },
    Object {
      "bmi": 24.7,
      "id": 2,
      "imperialgoalweight": 154.3,
      "imperialheight": 70.9,
      "imperialweight": 176.4,
      "metricgoalweight": 70,
      "metricheight": 180,
      "metricweight": 80,
      "standard": "Metric",
    },
    Object {
      "bmi": 26.2,
      "id": 3,
      "imperialgoalweight": 154.3,
      "imperialheight": 70.9,
      "imperialweight": 187.4,
      "metricgoalweight": 70,
      "metricheight": 180,
      "metricweight": 85,
      "standard": "Metric",
    },
  ],
  "length": 3,
}
```

I tried using `JSON.parse()` and no luck.
Any ideas as to how this can be done?

Comment: if that's the TEXT you are getting, then you're out of luck, because it isn't JSON ... but if that's what the object looks like in the console, then you already have an object, you don't need to parse it

Comment: Javascript does not give you strongly typed objects by default. Something like typescript will give you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text that you have given is probably what you are getting from console.In such a case,just remove the trailing commas.

Otherwise the text needs to be modified by removing the trailing commas as well as the data types(blue colored words)

The following is the valid JSON :

```
{
      "_array":  [
         {
          "bmi": 24.7,
          "id": 1,
          "imperialgoalweight": 154.3,
          "imperialheight": 70.9,
          "imperialweight": 176.4,
          "metricgoalweight": 70,
          "metricheight": 180,
          "metricweight": 80,
          "standard": "Metric"
        },
         {
          "bmi": 24.7,
          "id": 2,
          "imperialgoalweight": 154.3,
          "imperialheight": 70.9,
          "imperialweight": 176.4,
          "metricgoalweight": 70,
          "metricheight": 180,
          "metricweight": 80,
          "standard": "Metric"
        },
         {
          "bmi": 26.2,
          "id": 3,
          "imperialgoalweight": 154.3,
          "imperialheight": 70.9,
          "imperialweight": 187.4,
          "metricgoalweight": 70,
          "metricheight": 180,
          "metricweight": 85,
          "standard": "Metric"
        }
      ],
      "length": 3
}
```